# Self contained desktop database?

Tags: database

I currently want to move my data from excel into a self contained desktop database because the entries in excel is too large for it to handle(I'm talking a lot of data!!!). Is there a desktop database that  i can use?

Comment: Install mySQL or mongo db locally and off you go (depends on the shape of the data and how you want to query it)

Comment: Approximately how many rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/) or [NoSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) locally (i.e. on your desktop). Just because they're popular for networked use doesn't mean they *have* to be networked. In fact if you run through some of their tutorials they'll start you off with a local setup.

Comment: I also need something that would not require complex database queries to be able to edit the data(many people will be using it). does MySQL allows pulling in data from other database files? Like if had two MySQL databases.  Can I use data from the first in the second.?

Comment: That might be a good thing to ask in its own question, but you can start by looking at SQL Server Management Studio as an example of *one* kind of tool for working with databases.